# Java 1.7 atomic move does not work correctly?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

have this scenario:
On a file system have FFmpeg program which streams a video source from a webcam to youtube server. FFmpeg supports text filter where you can specify from which file it can read some static text to be then "overlayed" over video. The problem is if the file not exists or if someone else is writing in this file then the FFmpeg can crash.

In Java have done this example with StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE option :

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class FileMover {

    private void runIt() {
        Random r = new Random();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                try
                {
                  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("c:/video/temppodatki.txt", "UTF-8");
                  writer.println("Temp: " + ((int)(Math.random() * (40 - 10)) + 10)+ " °C");
                  writer.println("Sla: " +  ((int)(Math.random() * (37 - 30)) + 30)+ " PSU");
                  writer.close();    

                  //premaknemo fajl..
                  Path sourceFile = Paths.get("c:/video/temppodatki.txt");
                  Path destinationFile = Paths.get("c:/video/podatki.txt");
                  Files.move(sourceFile, destinationFile, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
                  System.out.println("move.." + new Date().toString());
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }, 0, 5 * (1000 * 1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileMover().runIt();
    }

}
```

this script writes into tmp file and after that it moves to file from which FFmpeg read. 
But the problem stil remain the same because randomly FFmpeg can crash with:

[image]

Is there some other approach to take?

Comment: Where do you call ffmpeg? Inside the `TimerTask` or outside it?

Comment: FFmpeg is separated process (run in terminal). Java app is there only to write values into a file which FFmpeg reads. But the trick here is that it can hang if the file is not "moved" atomically.

Comment: @Ferguson How do you call/handle ffmpeg with the file `temppodatki.txt`? Does ffmpeg constantly reads this file? I know hat Windows behaves different than Linux with file handling, perhaps you can test it with Linux? Otherwise always write in a new file, and call ffmpeg just some seconds after the file was moved.

Comment: Yes.. FFMpeg constantly read the text file. I will try to run my code on Ubuntu.. will let you know.

Comment: On Ubuntu it works fine. Have tried to run FFmpeg and java program which moves a file each half a second..  no crash after eight hours :)